# How to make sure that relation is unique from both sides of many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a model that acts as a many to many relation. Class name is `RelatedDocument` which is self explanatory, I basically use it to related `Document` class instances with one to another.

I ran into issues with validations so for example I have this in RelatedDocument class:

```
validates :document, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :related_document }
validates :related_document, presence: true
```

This works I m unable to create duplicate `document_id/related_document_id` row. However if I wanted to make this unique from the other side of the relation and change the validation to this :

```
validates :document, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :related_document }
validates :related_document, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :document }
```

This does not work the same from the other side. I was writing rspec test when I noticed this. How can I write validation or a custom validation method that prevents saving of the same id combination, no matter from which side they are?

**Update**

Per first comment in the comment section saying that the first uniqueness validation will take care of the boths sides, I say it doesn't simply because my rspec test fails, here are they :

```
describe 'relation uniqueness' do
    let!(:base_doc) { create(:document) }
    let!(:another_doc) { create(:document) }
    let!(:related_document) { described_class.create(document: another_doc, related_document: base_doc) }

    it 'raises ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, not allowing duplicate relation links' do
      expect { described_class.create!(document: another_doc, related_document: base_doc) }
        .to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
    end

    it 'raises ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, not allowing duplicate relation links' do
      expect { described_class.create!(document: base_doc, related_document: another_doc) }
        .to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
    end
  end
```

Second test fails.

Comment: Your first validation enforces a unique combination. It doesn't matter what "side" you view the combination from. So, you don't need the second validation.

Comment: @jvillian but my test says otherwise. In the example if I have doc1 and doc2, if I do `RelatedDocument.create!(document: doc1, related_document: doc2)` triggers uniqueness validation. However when I try `RelatedDocument.create!(document: doc2, related_document: doc1)` it doesn't that is what I m trying to say. The first validation does not account for both sides, at least in my rspec test

Comment: OOOOOOOH! I see. You could create a custom validation to check the relationship "from the other side". That has some second order implications that you'll want to make sure you are OK with.

Comment: @jvillian I tried something like `where(doc1 and doc2 OR doc2 and doc2).any?` Did not work, any ideas?

Comment: @rantingsonrails answer looks pretty solid. Would you ever want to do something like: `@document_1.related_documents` and get back all the related documents - regardless of the "direction" of the relationship? That'll be very tricky with your current heading.

Comment: @jvillian I can do `def self.related_to(document)
    where(
      'document_id = ? OR related_document_id = ?',
      document.id,
      document.id
    )
  end` on the RelatedDocument

Comment: Yes, you could surely do that. But, it will give you a set of `RelatedDocument` records where the `document` is in some relationship to some other `document`. But, it will not give you the set of `documents` that are related to `document` as `@document.related_documents` might be expected to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom validator should work here

```
validate :unique_document_pair

def unique_document_pair
  if RelatedDocument.exists?(:document => [self.document,self.related_document], :related_document => [self.document, self.related_document])
      errors.add :base, "error"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you'd like to consider an alternative to the custom validation that has already been provided, you could create reciprocal relationships each time a new record is added and use your existing validation.

For example, when I say that "Document A is related to Document B", I would then also insert a record stating that "Document B is related to Document A". You can keep your validations simple, and can more easily implement logic in the future for when you *don't* want a reciprocal relationship in some cases (perhaps the relationship is only reciprocated if the documents are from a different author).

Here is an untested example of the kind of model callbacks you would implement:

```ruby
create_table :documents do |t|
    t.string :title, null: false
end

create_table :related_documents do |t|
    t.integer :source_document_id, null: false
    t.integer :related_document_id, null: false
end

add_index :related_documents, [:source_document_id, :related_document_id], unique: true
add_foreign_key :related_documents, :documents, column: :source_document_id
add_foreign_key :related_documents, :documents, column: :related_document_id

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    # We have many document relationships where this document is the source document
    has_many :related_documents, foreign_key: :source_document_id

    validates :title,
        presence: true
end

class RelatedDocument < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :add_reciprocal_relationship
    after_destroy :remove_reciprocal_relationship

    belongs_to :source_document, class_name: Document
    belongs_to :related_document, class_name: Document

    validates :source_document,
        presence: true

    validates :related_document,
        presence: true,
        uniqueness: {
            scope: :source_document
        }

    private

    # Creates a reciprocal relationship
    def add_reciprocal_relationship
        RelatedDocument.find_or_create_by(
            related_document: self.source_document,
            source_document: self.related_document
        )
    end

    # Safely removes a reciprocal relationship if it exists
    def remove_reciprocal_relationship
        RelatedDocument.find_by(
            related_document: self.source_document,
            source_document: self.related_document
        )&.destroy
    end
end
```